# why maven tries to download from repo1,maven.org before my local nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

I have installed nexus, and configured my settings.xml to use my local nexus as repository, however, it always tries to fetch artifact from repo1.maven.org fist and then timeout before it goes to fetch from nexus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare in settings.xml that Nexus is a mirror for the external repos, as documented in the [Nexus book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) (which you should read).

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://nexushost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

We normally declare the repositories in the POM.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>internal</id>
        <url>http://192.168.0.10:8084/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
    ...
```

According to the docs, the info in your settings.xml is the "local" repository, meaning the M2_REPO copy in your hard drive.
http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Also, we set up Nexus as a mirror of external repos, thus you only declare these at the Nexus server.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the settings.xml.  Also, putting repositories in your POM files hurts stability in the long run: the POM will only work as long as you keep the repository at that exact location.  And now your POMs are not portable.  If you ever rename/renumber/reorganize, all your old POMs break.  The set of available repositories for dependency resolution is environment-specific; it should be managed independently from the project definition.

Comment: @Zac: Hm, maybe. But settings.xml is a *user* settings file, meaning that if I want the whole team working on a project to share this configuration they will all have to replicate these settings. I like people being able to just checkout from version control and be ready to work on the project without needing to configure any personal file if possible. Also, making sure the internal corporate repo URL is stable is easy to guarantee, even if moving locations, if you setup your name servers correctly... Instead of using a fixed IP as I did in the example, use an alias `http://nexus-server/...`

Comment: okay.  But you'll have to duplicate this information in every single project, and it does constrain the use of the POMs as I described.  I prefer to tell developers once: "version control over here, repository manager over here".  It's only one extra piece of information; you already have to tell them where to check out from.  But you should do whatever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.2.1 and 3.0.3 the mirror is ignored in certain cases if you're using the -gs option to override the default and specify a customized global settings file. Make sure, there's a valid settings.xml around in conf.